# codeigniter 3: Bootstrap 3 status-select outputs same value for any option selected

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table where drop-down option is being used in order to change the status of the cell. [see the sample snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pt1L.png)

Codeigniter view code

```
<?php foreach ($info as $s) : ?>
 // some lines here 

<td class="cell-status"> 
<div class="status-select"> 
<select name="<?php echo $s['Id'] ?>" class="select-color info-status" 
 id="<?php if ($s['isAccepted'] == 1) {echo "option-approved";} ?>
    <?php if ($s['isAccepted'] == 2) {echo "option-blocked";} ?>">  
 <option <?php if ($s['isAccepted'] == 1) {echo "selected";} ?> 
   id="option-approved" value="1">Approved</option> 
 <option <?php if ($s['isAccepted'] == 2) {echo "selected";} ?> 
   id="option-blocked" value="2">Blocked</option>
</select> 
</div>
</td>

// extra lines here 
<?php endforeach;
?>
```

My jQuery script is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.info-status').on("change",function () 
    {
        var Id= $(this).attr("name");
        var status =$('.info-status').val() 

        

        console.log(status)
        //console.log(Id)
    });
});
</script>
```

expectation, when I change the drop down from  *Approved* to *Blocked* the `console.log(status)` should output `2` and when I change from *Blocked* to *Approved* `console.log(status)` should output `1`.

However, no matter what option I select, the console output same value always (the first selected value after page reload). What went wrong, any idea?

Note: if I do `console.log(Id)` I am getting correct `Id` value.

Comment: Hi , instead of `$('.info-status').val()` use `$(this).val()` .

Comment: that is working